# Change some value each 5 inserts (MySQL Stored Procedure)

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

### The goal

Increase `CATEGORYID` by `1` each `5` inserts until the `WHILE` is done.

### The scenario

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE MaxAnnounces INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 5;
    DECLARE Counter INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE NewWeek INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 
            (SELECT WEEKID FROM announces_empire ORDER BY WEEKID DESC LIMIT 1);

    START TRANSACTION;
    WHILE Counter < MaxAnnounces DO
        INSERT INTO announces 
        (NAME, CAPTION, DESCRIPTION, IMAGEURL, LINK, CATEGORYID, WEEKID, YEARID)
        VALUES 
            ("Hello!", 
             "Click here.",
             "Can you tell me your name?",
             "example.com/img.jpg",
             "google.com",
             -- HERE I WANT TO INCREASE BY 1 EACH 5 INSERTS --
             40,
             2013);
        SET Counter = Counter + 1;
    END WHILE;
    COMMIT;
END
```

### The problem

I don't know the syntax.

### Problem highlight

Instead of `-- HERE I WANT TO INCREASE BY 1 EACH 5 INSERTS --` I was trying to do something in this way:

```
IF(Counter % 5, x + 1, 1),
```

Where `x` is a variable that I didn't defined yet.

**Guilherme, why can't you use this `IF`? What happens?** Doing this way the inserted value is always `1`.

Can someone give me a light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will using the following work:

```
CAST((Counter / 5) AS UNSIGNED)
```

OR

```
FLOOR(Counter / 5)
```

OR

```
FORMAT((Counter / 5),0)
```

It would look something like the following:

```
VALUES 
  ("Hello!", 
  "Click here.",
  "Can you tell me your name?",
  "example.com/img.jpg",
  "google.com",
  CAST((Counter / 5) AS UNSIGNED),
  40,
  2013);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that right after inside your while, at the beginning maybe ?

```
IF Counter % 5
BEGIN
    X = X + 1
END
```

and in your insert you use this variable. Don't forget to declare X.